# Different IPYTHON versions in EPD/CANOPY environment

Tags: ipython, enthought, jupyter-notebook, canopy

I am having an issue with plotting in the ipython notebook. Basically, the same code generates the plots I desire when I execute it in the Canopy editor command window, but balks in the notebook with just

> KeyError:matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x53e2f310

I was unable to make sense out of this discrepancy between the environments. Until I ran the `print(IPython.sys_info())` command in the two environments.

In Canopy `IPython.sys_info()` returns:

> {'commit_hash': 'c433019', 'commit_source': 'installation',
>   'default_encoding': 'UTF-8', 'ipython_path':
>   '/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython',
>   'ipython_version': '1.0.dev', 'os_name': 'posix', 'platform':
>   'Linux-3.8.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid',
>   'sys_executable':
>   '/home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python', 'sys_platform':
>   'linux2', 'sys_version': '2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 14 2013,
>   18:32:48) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]'}

In Notebook `IPython.sys_info()` returns:

> {'commit_hash': '177894e', 'commit_source': 'installation',
>   'default_encoding': 'UTF-8', 'ipython_path':
>   '/home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython',
>   'ipython_version': '0.13.1', 'os_name': 'posix', 'platform':
>   'Linux-3.8.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid',
>   'sys_executable':
>   '/home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python', 'sys_platform':
>   'linux2', 'sys_version': '2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 14 2013,
>   18:32:48) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]'}

I noticed that the Ipython_path point to different paths where the EPD files reside, which in turn point to different versions of ipython!!! I am not sure how this happened, nor exactly how to fix it. Such that both environments run the same version, which executes code the same way.

The snippet of code that causes a matplotlib failure with IPython version 0.13.1 is:

```
import pylab as pl
...
fig, axes = pl.subplots(len(evokeds), sharex=True, sharey=True, tight_layout=True,                     figsize=(8, 11), dpi=100)
figname = (data_path + subj_queue[r] + '/' + subj_queue[r] + '_evokeds.pdf')
for evoked, ax, cond in zip(evokeds, axes.flatten(), ['Known', 'Known-ctrl', 'Unknown', 'Unkown-ctrl']):
    evoked.plot(picks=mag_picks, axes=ax)
    ax.set_title('%s' % cond)
fig.savefig(figname, format='pdf')
```

Where evokeds is of class `list` of [Evoked](http://martinos.org/mne/generated/mne.fiff.Evoked.html?highlight=evoked.plot#mne.fiff.Evoked) objects generated by the third-party class function [mne.Epochs.average()](http://martinos.org/mne/generated/mne.Epochs.html#mne.Epochs). The plotting command that crashes matplotlib in IPython 0.13.1 is also a class function [mne.fiff.evoked.plot()](http://martinos.org/mne/generated/mne.fiff.Evoked.html?highlight=evoked.plot#mne.fiff.Evoked.plot) from the mne module. A publicly available example that will also generate the same plotting issue in an external Notebook with Ipython 0.13.1 is available [here](http://martinos.org/mne/auto_examples/plot_evoked_delayed_ssp.html). The error `evoked.plot(picks=mag_picks, axes=ax)` generates is a KeyError:. Here is a screen shot of the subplots:

[image]

This is the complete Traceback:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        25     figname = (data_path + subj_queue[r] + '/' + subj_queue[r] + '_evokeds.pdf')
>        26     for evoked, ax in zip(evokeds, axes.flatten()):
>   ---> 27         evoked.plot(picks=mag_picks, axes=ax)
>        28         ax.set_title('%s' % cond)
>        29     fig.savefig(figname, format='pdf')
>
> /usr/local/mne-python/mne/fiff/evoked.pyc in plot(self, picks,
>   exclude, unit, show, ylim, proj, xlim, hline, units, scalings, titles,
>   axes)
>       396         plot_evoked(self, picks=picks, exclude=exclude, unit=unit, show=show,
>       397                     ylim=ylim, proj=proj, xlim=xlim, hline=hline, units=units,
>   --> 398                     scalings=scalings, titles=titles, axes=axes)
>       399 
>       400     def plot_topomap(self, times=None, ch_type='mag', layout=None, vmax=None,
>
> /usr/local/mne-python/mne/viz.pyc in plot_evoked(evoked, picks,
>   exclude, unit, show, ylim, proj, xlim, hline, units, scalings, titles,
>   axes)    1213     1214             D = this_scaling * evoked.data[idx,
>   :]
>   -> 1215             pl.axes(ax)    1216             ax.plot(times, D.T)    1217             if xlim is not None:
>
> /home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc
>   in axes(*args, **kwargs)
>       650 
>       651     if isinstance(arg, Axes):
>   --> 652         a = gcf().sca(arg)
>       653     else:
>       654         rect = arg
>
> /home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc
>   in sca(self, a)    1196     def sca(self, a):    1197         'Set the
>   current axes to be a and return a'
>   -> 1198         self._axstack.bubble(a)    1199         for func in self._axobservers: func(self)    1200         return a
>
> /home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc
>   in bubble(self, a)
>        97         stack, to the top.
>        98         """
>   ---> 99         return Stack.bubble(self, self._entry_from_axes(a))
>       100 
>       101     def add(self, key, a):
>
> /home/kambiz/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc
>   in _entry_from_axes(self, e)
>        85 
>        86     def _entry_from_axes(self, e):
>   ---> 87         ind, k = dict([(a, (ind, k)) for (k, (ind, a)) in self._elements])[e]
>        88         return (k, (ind, e))
>        89
>
> KeyError: matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x56e401d0

Comment: Are you referring to a notebook opened inside Canopy or externally?

Comment: @punchagan I am referring to a notebook opened outside Canopy via `ipython --pylab=inline` in the terminal. I didn't know about a Notebook inside Canaopy! Should I be doing that? My assumption was that 'everything' is under Canopy. What concerns me is that there are two ipython version both under Canopy directories in different locations on the machine, as though there were two installations.

Comment: Getting different versions of IPython in the notebook started from outside Canopy and the shell inside Canopy shouldn't be anything alarming.  Canopy uses virtual environments to allow users to install their own versions of packages, without forcing them to use the version the application depends on.  The problem is else where. Can you post the code that doesn't run for you, to try and reproduce and debug the issue?

Comment: @punchagan I will edit the post to include the code. Also note that it involves a little known third party class function with a plot method; from a (electrophysiological) data analysis module called mne-python. Thus, I am not sure how much we might glean from it.